# How to block the installation of a particular app from Google Play?

Tags: applications, google-play-store, installation, instagram

I wish to block and disable the installation of a couple of applications such as social media applications of Instagram, Reddit and Discord.

Is there a particular way that the user is unable to install the application even after going to Google Play?

Is there a thing like add to Block-List? If there is a parental control feature to do this, how do you select particular applications only?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no such thing in Google Play Store (aka `com.android.vending`).